# Как выделить слово без цифр с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста как в данном примере с помощью регулярных выражений исключить строку
aqw378242ess@google.ru
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста в вопрос вашу регулярку и список проверочных строк в текстовом виде. Спасибо.

Comment: `\w` - эквивалентно `[A-Za-z0-9_]` можно просто вместо `\w` написать `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 1):

Замените `(\w+)` на `([a-zA-Z]+)`, чтоб не искались цифры.

Итоговый вариант: `([a-zA-Z]+)@google\.\w+`

Comment: Но тогда ещё `_` исключается. Также имеет смысл домен после точки сильнее ограничить.